# Calling free on a pointer to an extern variable in C

Tags: c, global-variables, free, allocation, extern

I would like to know the behavior of a C program calling free on a pointer to an extern variable. The background is that I'm a developer of a verifier analyzing C code and I wonder what my verifier should do if it encounters such a situation (e.g., say why the program is undefined - if it is).

To find out the behavior experimentally, I tried to run the following C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int g = 1;

int main() {
    int *ptr = &g;
    free(ptr);
    return g;
}
```

On a Debian GNU/Linux 7 system, this program crashes with an error message indicating that the pointer passed to free is invalid. On a Windows 7 system, I could run this program without any error message. Would you know of an explanation for this observation?

**UPDATE**
I did read the definition of `free`. My question aims at whether this definition actually rules out the possibility that such a program might reliably work on a standard-complying system (and not just by "it can do anything if the behavior is undefined"). So I would like to know if you could think of a configuration/system/whatever where this program does not expose undefined behavior. In other words: Are there conditions under which the call to `free` here would be defined properly according to the C standard?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. If it runs without error it just happens that you get away with `free(ptr)` but if you run the program on the next day it could crash even on the same computer. Remember: even a faulty program may appear to work.

Comment: Since you didn't allocate any memory (as far as we can tell), there is none to free. It worked today, it may not work tomorrow (or on the next invocation). Also, this is not all of your code as the 'unresolved extern' error (re: `extern int g = 1;`) would have stopped compilation prior to creating an executable.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I could compile this program as is using Clang.

Comment: What is so important in here? just turn on your compiler settings if you don't know what are you doing. **program.c:7:5: error: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘g’ free(ptr);**  Just read about free() and look again your code. A good compiler should warn you about this.
     ^**

Comment: @Michi For me it is important to explain the reason for an error (or the possibility that no error occurs) as appropriate as possible. The fact that I could run the program at least once on one system without an error showing up made me wonder whether there is more to know about this situation than the fact that free should only be called on pointers returned by memory management functions.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but if a compiler ignores such thing you should change that compiler. GCC without any settings turned on still complains for things like this: **warning: ‘g’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int g = 1;
            ^**

Comment: As stated by @Michi, if your compiler allows this you should get a new compiler

Comment: @KevinDTimm You might be right. However, my question does not concern how I would write programs in C but what my analyzer should tell users that program this way. And since I have no control over the compilers used by other programmers, changing "my" compiler does not help here.

Comment: @cryingshadow Your problem is not only the compiler, but also this **int *ptr = &g; + free(ptr);** . Why are you even trying to free() that pointer if there is no dynamic memory allocation ? So before you ask yourself why on Windows works and why on Linux not, well check your code Line-by-Line, read them and try to understand them. That's all.

Comment: @Michi The example is not a program that I would like to write myself but an example for an input program that my verifier could get. It does not make sense to fix that program since I could get wrong programs as input and should tell what exactly is wrong with that program.

Comment: So, my short answer is this: if your verifier encounters a `free`, it should look for a matching `xalloc`.  If one is not found, it should state that behavior at this point is undefined (per the standard).

Comment: @cryingshadow read a good book and you will have a better understand about your problem. Anyway don't read just a book about **C**, read also about compilers and of course about Operating System too. You already started wrong just at the beginning of your question. **I would like to know the behavior of a C program calling free on a pointer to an extern variable.** If you know about free() then will be no question, isn't it ?

Comment: @Michi I did read the definition of free before asking this question. I wondered (for example) whether a system is allowed to allocate extern variables using malloc or whether there would be other possibilities how calling free on a pointer to an extern variable could be ok. The background is that I want to give a description of the error which is as precise as possible. If I just say "This is undefined behavior because the pointer has not been returned by a memory management function" and there is a possibility that this explanation is wrong, my verifier might lose points.

Comment: @Michi I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @cryingshadow, Well according to your update you just showed that your knowledge is less then I was though. Please read a book and then see if your Question is needed again. By the way, why did you accepted that Answer if there is an Update needed? Ask another question will be a better idea at this point. I'm lost now :).

Comment: @Michi I accepted an answer since it seems to answer my question even with the update. I updated the question to make the problem discussed more clear right from the beginning when others read this (and there might of course be the case that someone comes up with a situation where free can be used safely that way - then I can still change the accepted answer, right?).

Comment: @cryingshadow I updated my answer in response to your updated question.  Please let me know if you still have concerns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard is unambigous about this.  Quoting document [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the closest approximation to C11 available online at no charge, section 7.22.3.3 para 2 (the specification of `free`):

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr`
>   to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If
>   `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.  Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,  the
>   behavior is undefined.

"Memory management functions" are listed at the beginning of 7.22.3: `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `aligned_alloc`.  (An implementation could add more such functions, e.g. [`posix_memalign`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign) -- read the notes at the bottom!)

Now, "the behavior is undefined" licenses an implementation to do *anything* when the situation occurs.  Crashing is common, but MSVC's runtime library is perfectly entitled to detect that a pointer is outside the "heap" and do nothing.  Experiment with debugging modes: there's probably a mode where it will crash the program instead.

As the author of a code-verifying tool, *you* should be maximally strict: if you can't *prove* that a pointer passed to `free` is either `NULL` or a value previously returned by a memory management function, flag that as an error.

---

Addendum: the somewhat confusing "or if the space has been deallocated..." clause is intended to prohibit double deallocation:

```
char *x = malloc(42);
free(x); // ok
free(x); // undefined behavior
```

... but beware of memory reuse:

```
char *x = malloc(42);
uintptr_t a = (uintptr_t)x;
free(x);
x = malloc(42);
uintptr_t b = (uintptr_t)x;

observe(a == b); // un*specified* behavior - must be either true or false,
                 // but no guarantee which
free(x); // ok regardless of whether a == b
```

---

Double addendum:

> Are there conditions under which the call to `free` here would be defined properly according to the C standard?

No.  If there were such a condition, it would have to appear *in the text of the standard* as an exception to the rule I quoted at the beginning of this answer, and there aren't any such exceptions.

However, there is a subtle variation to which the answer is 'yes':

> Could there be an *implementation* of C under which the behavior of the program shown is always well-defined?

For instance, an implementation in which `free` is documented to do nothing, regardless of its input, would qualify and is not even a crazy idea—many programs can get away with never *calling* `free`, after all.  But the behavior of the program is still undefined *according to the C standard*; it is just that the C implementation has chosen to make this particular UB scenario well-defined itself.

(From the language-lawyer perspective, *every implementation extension to the language* is a case of the implementation making an UB scenario well-defined.  Even nigh-ubiquitous things like `#include <unistd.h>`.)

Comment: I definitely want to flag this as an error but in a verification competition I would like to participate in, one must also give a "witness" for detected errors. So my question aims at how to describe the error in this case as appropriate as possible.

Comment: This will give a lot of spurious errors, such as when an `extern` variable is allocated by an initialization function. You can’t prove in the most general case that a variable is or isn't initialized without solving the Halting Problem. But surely being unable to prove that it is or isn't heap-allocated is a warning, and in the use case where code that isn't provably correct is wrong, that will be treated as an error?

Comment: @cryingshadow Could you be more specific about what it means to give a "witness" for detected errors? I don't know what the competition is looking for.

Comment: @zwol I have the same problem. ;) The competition is not very clear about this and just states that a human-readable witness for an error should be provided. Since I wanted to make sure that I don't lose points just because I did not notice that this situation could be ok if constraints x, y, and z are met, I wanted to make use of the community knowledge which is definitely bigger than mine. ;) The answers so far give me the impression that flagging this as error because the pointer cannot be proven to be returned by a memory management function is the way to go here.

Comment: @cryingshadow In that case I'd recommend giving the information most useful to a programmer trying to fix the bug: a trace of the control-flow path that leads to `free` being called on a non-heap pointer.  (This would be trivial in your example, but in a real program this kind of bug crops up when the initialization and the `free` are separated from each other by dozens of conditionals...)

Comment: @Lorehead Yes, tools like the OP is planning to build often have very high false positive rates; that's just the way it is with a memory-unsound language like C.  I have only limited experience with these things, but my impression is that the state of the art involves a first pass that's cheap and guaranteed to have no false *negatives*, at the expense of lots of false positives, and then a bunch of more careful and costly tests (flow-sensitive, value-sensitive, whole-program, ...) to prune down the false positives.

Answer (score 4):

You should only call `free` on a pointer which was previously allocated by `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc` or `aligned_alloc`. Otherwise it doesn't matter if it is "extern'd" or not.

---

**UPDATE #1**

It does not always run without errors, also check what the output of `valgrind` is:

```
==21569== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==21569==    at 0x4C29D2A: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21569==    by 0x4004FA: main (main.c:7)
==21569==  Address 0x6008e8 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "g"
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

`void free(void *ptr);`

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.

C11 Standard -- 7.22.3.3

Comment: That's what I thought. But that would not explain why the program runs without error on some system. I wonder whether a system is allowed to allocate extern variables using malloc (but even then I do not understand why the return value would not lead to an error).

Comment: @cryingshadow Because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @cryingshadow I updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: @PCLuddite I guess so. But do you have a reference for that? I could not find a passage in the C standard that would definitely declare such a situation as undefined behavior. It could well be the case that it is just not defined at all (and hence undefined) but I would like to confirm this on a stronger basis than "I could not find it" without reading all > 700 pages of the standard. ;)

Comment: @cryingshadow I updated my answer which quotes the standard

Comment: I’d have upvoted this except for the pedantic reason that the list of valid ways to get a pointer you can `free()` is not complete.

Comment: @Lorehead because the missing of the `aligned_alloc` function?

Comment: @PeterVaro and `NULL`, although that’s brought up in the quote. A given implementation often adds other ways, *e.g.* `posix_memalign()`, but those aren’t in the C standard.

Comment: @Lorehead that was one of the reasons I did not mentioned `aligned_alloc` in the first place, because IIRC that's only part of the later standards, and the OP did not specify any standards at all..

Comment: @PeterVaro This is also a problem for me since I also do not know whether the competition means the latest standard or another specific version when it says "the C standard". It might be that I'm too worried but the answers here did raise my confidence in the way I would like to handle the situation in my verifier.

Comment: @cryingshadow "competition"? almost 50 minutes ago I added a quote from the standard, which I specified as: `C11`. I think it is more than enough information. Not to mention, it has been almost an hour passed, and your questions has all been answered, but you did not accepted any of the answers. If you have further questions, I suggest you to accept an answer, and open a new one specifically asking what is not clear about the whole memory managment. Although I first recommend you to read the whole "chapter" from the standard which has the same title. (memory management)

Comment: @cryingshadow also, if you want to chat about C in general, you are more than welcome to do that in the [Stackoverflow C Chat-room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c)

Comment: @PeterVaro Sorry, I mentioned the competition in the comments to another answer by zwol. I updated the question to make my focus more clear.

Answer (score 2):

When you call free on a pointer that was not previously allocated by malloc, calloc or realloc, the behavior is undefined.  That means it can have different behavior in different tool chains, and also different behavior at different times in the same program.

Whether it generates a crash with an error message depends on whether that specific platform's library implementation checks for the validity of the pointer.  Since checking for validity can have non-zero performance cost, not all programs will do it.  Also, even if the implementation does some validity checks, it might not detect all invalid pointers.

One implementation may detect that a pointer to the static memory area can not be a valid heap pointer; others may treat it like a valid heap pointer and try to add the "free" memory back to the heap, corrupting the heap as well as values adjacent to your extern value in static memory in the process.  The program may run fine, for a time, with the corrupted heap and static memory.

This is why there are alternate, instrumented heap implementations available for C that provide additional checking.

Answer (score 2):

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **7.22.3.3 The `free` function**
> ...
> 2 The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
> available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
> the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
> function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the
> behavior is undefined.**

Emphasis mine.

Since the behavior is undefined, *any* action taken by the compiler or the run time environment is acceptable.  It may reject the code with a diagnostic, it may translate the code with a diagnostic, it may translate the code without a diagnostic, your code may crash at runtime, your code may appear to run without any issues, your code may invoke Rogue, etc.